# What to look for in a phone that will be kept for many years?

Tags: performance

I am asking this on behalf of someone who strongly dislikes changing their devices. What should I pay attention to when purchasing an Android phone with the intention to keep using it in the long term (at least 5 years)?

As you know, after a certain age, smartphones tend to start having problems, such as slowing down (perhaps to the point of unusability), lack of security updates, complete battery failure, and probably a bunch of other things I did not think of. It is also unclear if spending more (e.g. flagship vs mid-range) actually helps with longevity. This is where I need your help: advice in preparing for the future. I am *not* looking for specific model recommendations. Instead, I am looking for information about what features/properties to look for that will help the device function well a few years down the road.  This device will be for "normal" everyday use (i.e. calls, messaging, photos, navigation, social media, etc.)

Comment: I am disappointed that my question was closed within 5 minutes of posting as a "duplicate" of another post which barely touches on an answer. The question might be similar, but the other thread does not have good answers, and by closing my questions you are denying me the possibility to receive better answers. Not a very good first experience.

Comment: That kind of question (like Why is Fairphone better than Samsung) attracts opinion-based answers what is not very suitable for this site. Descripe your single problem with android device so that others can suggest possible solution.

Comment: @Ship as the one who closed the question as a duplicate, I think it does answer your question: unlockable bootloader and good support for custom ROM (+replaceable battery if needed). Most Android manufacturers only have at most 3-years-of-support policy. Longer than that, you need to rely on their community support like custom ROMs. Also, this question is basically the same, and anyone can still answer the linked question so that all info is centralized, not fragmented. Otherwise, please [edit] and explain *why* the question is not a duplicate, and the community can evaluate and reopen it.

Comment: Yes, that answer basically says "custom ROMs and replaceable batteries". Customs ROMs require technical knowledge most don't have, and replaceable batteries are basically non-existent (and conflict with the other suggestion of getting a popular model). Overall, it is not a very useful answer.

Comment: @Ship whether the answer is useful or not for you, unfortunately that's how the Android market works. Call me curious though for what kind of answers that may satisfy you without contradicting the facts. (Also, alecxs mentioned [Fairphone](https://www.fairphone.com/en/), which is possibly one of the niche Android smartphones that may satisfy your requirements)

Comment: "technical knowledge most don't have" that's one heck of an enthusiast...